# AWS CodePipeline, build failed and getting error

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

I am trying build and Angular7 project and deploy to S3 but am getting the following error. How can I resolve it?

```
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:49 Waiting for agent ping 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:51 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:56 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:56 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src345798432/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/CodeCommit-May20 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:56 YAML location is /codebuild/readonly/buildspec.yml 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:56 Processing environment variables 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:56 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src345798432/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/CodeCommit-May20 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:56 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED 
[Container] 2019/05/21 04:08:56 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: This build image requires selecting at least one runtime version.
```

Comment: I also had the same usecase. I used codebuild to build my angular application and push build artifacts in s3. I was built successfully in my case. I want to know which Image you are using? Is it standard:1.0 or standard:2.0?

Answer (score 19):

> If you use the `aws/codebuild/standard:2.0` CodeBuild managed image, you
>   must specify a runtime version in the `runtime-versions` section of the
>   buildspec file.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-build-must-specify-runtime

This is how you specify `runtime-versions:` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#runtime-versions-buildspec-file

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had the same error message because I had the `buildspec.yml` file in a sub-folder, and not in the project root.

If that is the case, you need to manually configure the `buildspec.yml` file location in the codebuild project console.

Comment: same with me, hard to guess with that message. thanks mate